# From the Young tableaux to the algebra

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, representation-theory

Given the following Young tableaux

[image]

for $SU(3)$, how can I deduce that it corresponds to the adjoint representation?
I was thinking that the dimension of this representation is 8, as in the case of the adjoint representation. Is this sufficient?

Comment: For SU(3), you know a height -2 tower is an antiquark ($\bar 3$) and a plain box a quark (3), so this is $q\bar q$, the adjoint. Can you now write down the YT for the adjoint of SU(5)? You need not compute the dimensionality.

Comment: I think is the same YT, am I wrong?

Comment: The first column is 4-high, the second 1.

Answer (score 1):

One can compute the  the weights by filling in the numbers 1,2,3 according to the rule for semi-standard tableaux (not decreasing along the rows, strictly increasing down the columns).  Each of the eight possible tableaux gives the eigenvalues of $\lambda_3$ (the number of 1's minus the number of 2's) and $\lambda_8$ (number of 1's plus number of 2's minus twice the number of 3's all divided by  $\sqrt 3$).  If you plot them you will recognise  the weight diagram of   the octet (adjoint) rep.

Comment: But following another path... if I start from the action of the group on a three-indices tensor: 
$\psi^{ijk} \rightarrow U^i_l U^j_m U^k_n \psi^{lmn}$
the I can pass to the action of the algebra on the same tensor:
$\psi^{ijk} \rightarrow u^i_l \psi^{ljk} + u^j_l \psi^{ilk} + u^k_l \psi^{ijl}$.
Now is it possible to prove the the action of the algebra on $\psi$ is the adjoint action? Maybe writing explicitely the form of $\psi$...some hints?

Comment: @dfgoe55 You need to properly symmetrize your tensor first, else what you have lives in $(3,0)\oplus (1,1)\oplus (0,0)$.  It so happens that the only irrep of $su(3)$ with dim=8 is the adjoint, but such luck does not necessarily hold in general.  The solution of this answer is unambiguous and would work in general.

Comment: The structrure of the tensor is the following $\psi^{ijk} = \phi^{ijk} - \phi^{kji} + \phi^{jik} - \phi^{kij}$...is it wrong?